# How to create not persisted instance of active record class in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, strategy-pattern

I am new to ruby and ruby on rails and I am trying to build a blog. This blog has articles, which are extending ActiveRecord::Base.

They have also some relations to tags or comments.

Now, I want to have the possibility to load articles from other sources than the DB. For example from my website, which is not the same app and provides a REST API to load articles.

How could I do this?

With an ActiveArticle which extends ActiveRecord::Base and an ExternalArticle which does not extends and an ArticleModule to implement the same features?

That seems to be not the right way. 
Thanks

Comment: You got me confused a little -- you say you want the articles to be available on your website. Is this going to be in the same Rails app, or not?

Comment: I updated it above. No it is another application with a REST API. I want to load the articles from my db via active record and from this API. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I thought as much - do you have any details on the API interface?

Comment: It returns my articles as an array which is encoded as JSON. I dont have a problem with reading it and create objects from this JSON but with using my active record class for this without persisting it.

Comment: I think you've got a good answer for this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good chunk of what makes up a Rails model lives not in `ActiveRecord`, but in `ActiveModel`.

```
class ExternalArticle
  include ActiveModel::Model
end
```

will give you functionality like validations, callbacks, compatibility with URL helpers and so on.

See [Railscast #219](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model?view=asciicast) for a short overview.

However, ActiveModel does not give you associations to other models. If you need those, the [activerecord-tableless gem](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless) might help.

Edit:

I see now that your non-persisted model objects come from a REST API. Take a look at [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) as well; it used to be part of Rails, but has been extracted into a separate gem as of Rails 4. It is basically ActiveRecord for remote objects.

Comment: It is to complex to look through all resources you gave me, but I am sure that you helped me a lot. I think ActiveResource is the answer but to understand more of ruby and rails I will dig through ActiveModel::Model. Thank you so much.